# マルチサイト構築に失敗　復旧できず

Tags: wordpress

wordpressにてマルチサイト運用を試みたところ、
既存サイトに影響が出てしまいました。
元に戻すこともできません。
どなたか解決方法をご教示いただけませんでしょうか？

■環境
wordpress　ver:3.5.1
サーバ　　　ファーストサーバ

■既存サイトへの影響
・投稿記事が表示されない
・固定ページが表示されない
・MW WP Formで作成した部分が表示されない

■作業した内容
①プラグインを全て無効化
②wp-config.php（/ssl/wordpress/）に下記を追加して更新

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'a-mics.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

③.htaccess（/ssl/）を下記のものに更新

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

④プラグインを全て無効化
⑤管理画面　再ログイン
⑥プラグインを全て有効化

下記の記事を参考に作業しました。
http://webdesignerwork.jp/wordpress/multisite_blog/

現在はwp-config.php、.htaccessを元に戻しましたが、
既存サイトへの影響は変わらない状態です。

元の状態に戻すには、どのような方法が考えられますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: お困りのようですね。ただ質問の内容がはっきりしないため回答が得られにくいと感じました。解決したいのは、既存サイト元に戻す方法でしょうか。それともマルチサイトの構築を成功させることでしょうか。また `添付ファイルのもの` と書かれていますが 意味が分かりません。何かを省略しているのでしたらできるだけ詳細に書いてみてください。

Comment: wp-configに正しいデータベースが設定されていますか？

chownやchmodでアクセス許可、
パーマリンク設定とhtaccessの見直しなどどうでしょう

Comment: @take88 ありがとうございます。質問内容本文を修正しました。
解決したいのは、既存サイトを元に戻す方法です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

DBは生きているんですよね？
なにしたのか分からないですが、
DBのダンプを取ってWP入れ直した後にDB復元してはどうでしょうか？
見ている限りWPの設定と配下のディレクトリのパーミッションとかいじくってるだけっぽいので
WP入れ直してデータ差し込めば戻るんじゃないでしょうか？
上記作業前にバックアップは必ずしてくださいね。
画像とプラグインは手動で入れなおして下さい。

また、マルチサイトを行き成り稼働中のサイト巻き込んで行うより、
一度仮環境を作って検証してから行った方が良いかと思います……今更ですが……

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
タイミングを見て、助言いただいた内容を試してみます。

一度仮環境での検証の件、まったくの同感です。なぜあの時安易に作業してしまったのか。悔やんでも悔やみきれません。